# Convert an integer to a byte array

Tags: go, type-conversion

I have a function which receives a `[]byte` but what I have is an `int`, what is the best way to go about this conversion ?

```
err = a.Write([]byte(myInt))
```

I guess I could go the long way and get it into a string and put that into bytes, but it sounds ugly and I guess there are better ways to do it.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I agree with Brainstorm's approach: assuming that you're passing a machine-friendly binary representation, use the `encoding/binary` library.  The OP suggests that `binary.Write()` might have some overhead.  Looking at [the source](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/binary/binary.go) for the implementation of `Write()`, I see that it does some runtime decisions for maximum flexibility.

```
func Write(w io.Writer, order ByteOrder, data interface{}) error {
    // Fast path for basic types.
    var b [8]byte
    var bs []byte
    switch v := data.(type) {
    case *int8:
        bs = b[:1]
        b[0] = byte(*v)
    case int8:
        bs = b[:1]
        b[0] = byte(v)
    case *uint8:
        bs = b[:1]
        b[0] = *v
    ...
```

Right?  Write() takes in a very generic `data` third argument, and that's imposing some overhead as the Go runtime then is forced into encoding type information.  Since `Write()` is doing some runtime decisions here that you simply don't need in your situation, maybe you can just directly call the encoding functions and see if it performs better.

Something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    bs := make([]byte, 4)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(bs, 31415926)
    fmt.Println(bs)
}
```

Let us know how this performs.

Otherwise, if you're just trying to get an ASCII representation of the integer, you can get the string representation (probably with [`strconv.Itoa`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa)) and cast that string to the `[]byte` type.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    bs := []byte(strconv.Itoa(31415926))
    fmt.Println(bs)
}
```

Comment: Ended up using a small variation of your first suggestion. Should have dived into the implementation myself, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 35):

Check out the ["encoding/binary"](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package. Particularly the [Read](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read) and [Write](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Write) functions:

```
binary.Write(a, binary.LittleEndian, myInt)
```

Comment: After benchmarking the "enconding/binary" way, it takes almost 4 times  longer than int -> string -> byte

Comment: But what byte representation does your consumer expect for integers?  Surely not the ASCII representation?  Please clarify.

Comment: @vascop it does. But `binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(bs, value)` is much faster than int -> string -> byte.

Comment: Make sure to check the err returned by `binary.Write`, see @Agniva De Sarker's answer. Does not work directly with the `int` type, you need to cast it to `int64` or something similar.

Answer (score 28):

Sorry, this might be a bit late. But I think I found a better implementation on the go docs.

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
var num uint16 = 1234
err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, num)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("binary.Write failed:", err)
}
fmt.Printf("% x", buf.Bytes())
```

Comment: this answer should be on top, it is the only meaningful one.

Answer (score 3):

i thought int type has any method for getting int hash to bytes, but first i find math / big method for this
https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/

```
var f int = 52452356235;          // int
var s = big.NewInt(int64(f))      // int to big Int
var b = s.Bytes()                 // big Int to bytes
// b - byte slise
var r = big.NewInt(0).SetBytes(b) // bytes to big Int
var i int = int(r.Int64())        // big Int to int
```

https://play.golang.org/p/VAKSGw8XNQq

However, this method uses an absolute value.
If you spend 1 byte more, you can transfer the sign

```
func IntToBytes(i int) []byte{
    if i > 0 {
        return append(big.NewInt(int64(i)).Bytes(), byte(1))
    }
    return append(big.NewInt(int64(i)).Bytes(), byte(0))
}
func BytesToInt(b []byte) int{
    if b[len(b)-1]==0 {
        return -int(big.NewInt(0).SetBytes(b[:len(b)-1]).Int64())
    }
    return int(big.NewInt(0).SetBytes(b[:len(b)-1]).Int64())
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/mR5Sp5hu4jk

or new(https://play.golang.org/p/7ZAK4QL96FO)

(The package also provides functions for fill into an existing slice)

https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.FillBytes

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option, based on the Go source code [1]:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/binary"
   "fmt"
   "math/bits"
)

func encodeUint(x uint64) []byte {
   buf := make([]byte, 8)
   binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(buf, x)
   return buf[bits.LeadingZeros64(x) >> 3:]
}

func main() {
   for x := 0; x <= 64; x += 8 {
      buf := encodeUint(1<<x-1)
      fmt.Println(buf)
   }
}
```

Result:

```
[]
[255]
[255 255]
[255 255 255]
[255 255 255 255]
[255 255 255 255 255]
[255 255 255 255 255 255]
[255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
[255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
```

Much faster than `math/big`:

```
BenchmarkBig-12         28348621                40.62 ns/op
BenchmarkBit-12         731601145                1.641 ns/op
```

1. https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.16.5/src/encoding/gob/encode.go#L113-L117

Answer (score 1):

Adding this option for dealing with basic uint8 to byte[] conversion

```
foo := 255 // 1 - 255
ufoo := uint16(foo) 
far := []byte{0,0}
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(far, ufoo)
bar := int(far[0]) // back to int
fmt.Println("foo, far, bar : ",foo,far,bar)
```

output :
`foo, far, bar :  255 [255 0] 255`

Answer (score 1):

This is the most straight forward (and shortest (and safest) (and maybe most performant)) way:

`buf.Bytes()` is of type bytes slice.

```golang
    var val uint32 = 42
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, val)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("binary.Write failed:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("% x\n", buf.Bytes())
```

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/74819602/589493

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26114897/589493 that should be ahead here

Answer (score 0):

Convert Integer to byte slice.

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "log"
)

func IntToBytes(num int64) []byte {
    buff := new(bytes.Buffer)
    bigOrLittleEndian := binary.BigEndian
    err := binary.Write(buff, bigOrLittleEndian, num)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    return buff.Bytes()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simple way is using protobuf, see the [Protocol Buffer Basics: Go](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial)

define message like

```
message MyData {
  int32 id = 1;
}
```

get more in [Defining your protocol format](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial#defining-your-protocol-format)

```golang
// Write
out, err := proto.Marshal(mydata)
```

read more in [Writing a Message](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial#writing_a_message)

Answer (score 0):

Try [math/big](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big) package to convert bytes array to int and to convert int to bytes array.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    // Convert int to []byte
    var int_to_encode int64 = 65535
    var bytes_array []byte = big.NewInt(int_to_encode).Bytes()
    fmt.Println("bytes array", bytes_array)

    // Convert []byte to int
    var decoded_int int64 = new(big.Int).SetBytes(bytes_array).Int64()
    fmt.Println("decoded int", decoded_int)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Ignore endianness, and do it directly for any type:

```golang
func toBytes[T any](val T) []byte {
    return unsafe.Slice((*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&val)), unsafe.Sizeof(val))
}
```

(also consider adding [Integer constraint](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/constraints#Integer) on type T)

Step 2. Do you really need portability between machines with different endianness? Ok, here's an idea:

```golang
func toLEBytes[T any](val T) []byte {
    bytes := toBytes(val)
    if runningOnBigEndian() {
        slices.Reverse(bytes)
    }
    return bytes
}
```

The only thing you need is to implement `runningOnBigEndian()`. Start by reading this question answers:
[Any better way to check endianness in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332658/any-better-way-to-check-endianness-in-go)

Also note that reversing bytes is fine, because endianness is the order or sequence of **bytes**, not bits.

[image: Endian example]

Answer (score -6):

What's wrong with converting it to a string?

```
[]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%d", myint))
```

Comment: This encodes the ASCII representation of the number, not the number itself.

Comment: fmt.Sprintf is 2 times slower than the following code https://play.golang.org/p/g-yTtgOxeNT  if you are ready to give up the decimal representation

Comment: @Matt ah Thank you :)

Comment: Pushing Larytet's solution a little faster: https://play.golang.org/p/JZ8CBVf6QNO