# Converting int32 to byte array in go

Tags: go

I am using big.NewInt(int64(e)).Bytes() to convert an int32 to a byte array.
Is there a more elegant way to do this?

I expect AQAB to be the base64 encoded value of e

http://play.golang.org/p/M46X7OpZpu

```
const e = 65537

func base64Encode(b []byte) string {
  return strings.TrimRight(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(b), "=")
}

func main() {
  fmt.Printf("exp %d\n", e)

  b := make([]byte, 4)
  binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(b, e)
  fmt.Printf("b: BigEndian.PutUint32 %x (Bad) %s\n", b, base64Encode(b))

  b2 := make([]byte, 4)
  binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(b2, e)
  for i := range b2 {
    if b2[i] != 0 {
    b2 = b2[i:]
    break
     }
  }
  fmt.Printf("b2: BigEndian.PutUint32 %x (Good) %s\n", b2, base64Encode(b2))

  b4 := big.NewInt(int64(e)).Bytes()
  fmt.Printf("b4: big.NewInt(int64(e)).Bytes() %x (Good) %s\n", b4, base64Encode(b4))
}
```

Output:

```
exp 65537
b: BigEndian.PutUint32 00010001 (Bad) AAEAAQ
b2: BigEndian.PutUint32 010001 (Good) AQAB
b4: big.NewInt(int64(e)).Bytes() 010001 (Good) AQAB

exp 1
b: BigEndian.PutUint32 00000001 (Bad) AAAAAQ
b2: BigEndian.PutUint32 01 (Good) AQ
b4: big.NewInt(int64(e)).Bytes() 01 (Good) AQ

exp 1000000
b: BigEndian.PutUint32 000f4240 (Bad) AA9CQA
b2: BigEndian.PutUint32 0f4240 (Good) D0JA
b4: big.NewInt(int64(e)).Bytes() 0f4240 (Good) D0JA
```

Edit:

I've benchmarked b2 and b4:

```
b2  1000000000          68.1 ns/op         8 B/op          1 allocs/op
b4  200000000          248 ns/op          90 B/op          3 allocs/op
```

I'll use b2 for now...

Answer (score 5):

For this kind of task I think your first options should always be using [`encoding/binary`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) and, if that is insufficient, bitwise math. However, in some cases the overhead of copying data is too large or these *safe* solutions are too slow:

While I would not call it elegant you can use Go's [`unsafe`](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) and [`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)* packages to do this very quickly. Just remember, this does not copy the data; rather, it just gives you another "view" of it. And being well- unsafe means that you need to be very careful- (hello units tests and code review) and keep in mind you are breaking Go's [memory safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_safe). However, when execution speed is the dominating concern and your team agrees [`unsafe`](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) is warranted, [`unsafe`](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) can seldom be beat.

```
const BYTES_IN_INT32 = 4

func UnsafeCaseInt32ToBytes(val int32) []byte {
    hdr := reflect.SliceHeader{Data: uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&val)), Len: BYTES_IN_INT32, Cap: BYTES_IN_INT32}
    return *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&hdr))
}

func UnsafeCastInt32sToBytes(ints []int32) []byte {        
    length := len(ints) * BYTES_IN_INT32
    hdr := reflect.SliceHeader{Data: uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&ints[0])), Len: length, Cap: length}
    return *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&hdr))
}
```

*Note: You may want to use [`SizeOf`](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Sizeof) rather than a constant. I like the constant better.

Update: here are some benchmark results:

```
BenchmarkB2     20000000     88.7  ns/op
BenchmarkB4     5000000     309    ns/op
BenchmarkUnsafe 1000000000    2.25 ns/op
```

Comment: Not only does `unsafe` break memory safety, it introduces endianness issues.

Comment: @larsmans: As does bit shifting things yourself; furthermore, `encoding/binary` itself is endian-aware (http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#pkg-variables).

Comment: No, shifting is safe. `x >> 24` will get the high-order 8 bits of `x`, regardless of endianness.

Comment: @voidlogic: Using proper mask to isolate a byte from a 32bit number is endianness independent as well. Also, the OP question is not asking about []int32 -> []byte, but int32 -> []byte, so I guess your answer is not valid. (-1)

Comment: A horrible and unnecessary solution.

Comment: @peterSO How can you say that without even knowing the users use case? unsafe is too be avoided, that does not mean its never valid to use. Its not like I omitted the usual warnings involved in using it.

Comment: Interesting... I did a B3 case using bit shifting but I thought it was really ugly and error prone. I didn't benchmark it though.

Answer (score -1):

This is the most straight forward (and shortest (and safest) (and maybe most performant)) way:

`buf.Bytes()` is of type bytes slice.

```golang
    var val uint32 = 42
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, val)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("binary.Write failed:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("% x\n", buf.Bytes())
```