# Go JSON parsing

Tags: json, go, webserver, unmarshalling, flickr

I'm new to Go.
I have been trying to get the photos from Flickr using [their API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/) but I'm facing an issue parsing the JSON response.

I have been writing the server in Go to handle the web service calls.
My Output looks something like this:

```
{
    "photos": {
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 3583,
        "perpage": 100,
        "total": "358260",
        "photo": [
            {
                "id": "18929318980",
                "owner": "125299498@N04",
                "secret": "505225f721",
                "server": "469",
                "farm": 1,
                "title": "❤️ Puppy Dog Eyes❤️ #Cute #baby #havanese #puppy #love #petsofinstagram #akc #aplacetolovedogs #all_little_puppies #americankennelclub #beautiful #bestanimal #puppies #cutestdogever #dog #doglife #doglover #dogoftheday",
                "ispublic": 1,
                "isfriend": 0,
                "isfamily": 0
            },
            {
                "id": "18930020399",
                "owner": "125421155@N06",
                "secret": "449f493ebc",
                "server": "496",
                "farm": 1,
                "title": "Titt tei hvem er du for en liten tass  Osvald og King  #cat#kitten #bordercollie #puppy#dog",
                "ispublic": 1,
                "isfriend": 0,
                "isfamily": 0
            },
            {
                "id": "18929979989",
                "owner": "131975470@N02",
                "secret": "7da344edcb",
                "server": "498",
                "farm": 1,
                "title": "Shame, Shame",
                "ispublic": 1,
                "isfriend": 0,
                "isfamily": 0
            }
             ]
    },
    "stat": "ok"
}
```

When I'm trying to run the code it's showing:

```
cannot use jsonData.Photos.Photo[i].Id (type int) as type []byte in argument to w.Write
```

My code is given below:

```
package main

import(
        "os"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "io/ioutil"
        "encoding/json"
        "github.com/gorilla/mux"

)
type Result struct {
        Photos struct {
        Page int `json: "page"`
        Pages int `json: "pages"`
        PerPage int `json: "perpage"`
        Total int `json: "total"`
        Photo []struct {
            Id int `json: "id"`
            Owner string `json: "owner"`
            Secret string `json: "secret"`
            Server int `json: "server"`
            Farm int `json: "farm"`
            Title string `json: "title"`
            IsPublic int `json: "ispublic"`
            IsFriend int `json: "isfriend"`
            IsFamily int `json: "isfamily`
            } `json: "photo"`
    } `json: "photos"`
    Stat string `json: "stat"`
}

func main() {

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true);
    router.HandleFunc("/Index", Index)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8084", router))
}

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    url := "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=6b54d86b4e09671ef6a2a8c02b7a3537&text=cute+puppies&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"
    res, err := http.Get(url)
     if err != nil{
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
     }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
     }

     jsonData := &Result{}
     err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &jsonData)
     for i := 0;i < len(jsonData); i++ {
        w.Write(jsonData.Photos.Photo[i].Id)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with your model, that works just fine. You've already finished deserialzing (without errors) when the error occurs which is on this line; `w.Write(jsonData.Photos.Photo[i].Id)`. You're passing an int when it needs to be a byte array.

This answer explains how to do the conversion; [Convert an integer to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888357/convert-an-integer-to-a-byte-array)

So, to make your code into some working form;

```
import "encoding/binary"

buffer := make([]byte, 4)
for i := 0;i < len(jsonData.Photos.Photo); i++ {
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(buffer, jsonData.Photos.Photo[i].Id)
        w.Write(buffer)
     }
```

Note that is writing the binary representation of your value as an unsigned 32 bit int with little endian bit order. That *may not* work for you. I can't say what will so you gotta make some decisions there like what bit order you want, if you need signed vs unsigned ect.

EDIT: To make the above work I guess you gotta do a cast from int to uint32 as well. Looking more closely at the answer I linked to you can do this instead which is cleaner/simpler imo.

```
import "strconv"

for _, p := range jsonData.Photos.Photo {
            w.Write([]byte(strconv.Itoa(p.Id)))
         }
```

Second EDIT: There's many ways to convert an int to binary. Another good option would be; `func Write(w io.Writer, order ByteOrder, data interface{}) error`

I believe in your code you could use that like;

```
  import "encoding/binary"

  for i := range jsonData.Photo.Photos {
            binary.Write(w, binary.LittleEndian, jsonData.Photos.Photo[i].Id)
         }
```

http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Write

EDIT: Updated the three examples to have working for loops of different varieties.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. but Im still getting an error : cannot use jsonData.Photos.Photo[i].Id (type int) as type uint32 in argument to binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32

Comment: @user3502049 ah yeah, I should have looked at the method definition. I'll edit with a better option. You could do another cast from int to uint32 but anyway, I think this is easier.

Comment: I tried replacing the code with the first edit you gave but still getting an error : invalid argument jsonData (type *Result) for len

Comment: @user3502049 that's because this code; `len(jsonData)` isn't valid. In your for loop. You probably want `len(jsonData.Photos.Photo)` instead but you can also use the range function `for p, i := range jsonData.Photos.Photo` p will point to the current item and i will be the index which it's at.

Comment: Can I use it like this : `for p,i := range jsonData.Photos.Photo {
            w.Write([]byte(strconv.Itoa(p[i].Id)))
         }`; as its giving an error : invalid operation: p[i] (type int does not support indexing)

Comment: @user3502049 look at my updated answer. Also, check out some resources on the for loop syntax. I misspoke slightly in my comment above. http://golangtutorials.blogspot.com/2011/06/control-structures-go-for-loop-break.html

Comment: Hei the updated code is getting compiled but Im getting only zeros as a response

Comment: @user3502049 my guess is that's because you have Id as an int in your model but in the json the type is actually a string. All those numbers in quotes are actually strings, you'll have to write some code to convert them to ints if you need them in that form. Otherwise you could just get rid of that byte stuff. Like this `w.Write([]byte(strconv.Itoa(p.Id)))` could just be `w.Write([]byte(p.Id))`. Sorry, I probably should have noticed that earlier but you got many errors and obv I'm not compiling or anything, just editing on here.