# How to return the port number in 2 bytes to client in socks5 proxy?

Tags: go, binary, network-programming, binary-data, socks

I am trying to implement socks5 proxy server.
Most things are clear according to the rfc but I'm stuck interpreting client port and writing my port number in bytes.

I made a function that tkes an int and returns 2 bytes. This function first converts number into binary then literally splits the bits as string then converts them back to byte.However this seems wrong because if the right most bits are 0 they are lost.
Here is the function

```
func getBytesOfInt(i int) []byte {
    binary := fmt.Sprintf("%b", i)
    if i < 255 {
        return []byte{byte(i)}
    }
    first := binary[:8]
    last := binary[9:]
    fmt.Println(binary, first, last)
    i1, _ := strconv.ParseInt(first, 2, 64)
    i2, _ := strconv.ParseInt(last, 2, 64)
    return []byte{byte(i1), byte(i2)}
}
```

Can you please explain me how am i supposed to parse the number and get 2 bytes and most importantly how am i going to cast it back to an integer.

Currently if you give 1024 to this function it will return `[]byte{0x80, 0x0}` which is 128 in decimals but as you see the right bits are lost theres only one 0 which is useless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert an integer to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888357/convert-an-integer-to-a-byte-array)

Comment: That's a duplicate of the many convert integer to binary questions here, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888357/convert-an-integer-to-a-byte-array. Look at the encoding/binary package, which is far more efficient then going to a string and back.

Comment: @Matthias247 binary.Write results something totally unusable for my case it gives me more bytes than i need

Comment: Then use only the bytes that you need. Or convert to a short before converting to binary.

Comment: The code in https://github.com/golang/net/tree/master/proxy may be of use to you. See the _test.go file for the server side of the protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple problem. First :8 and 9: miss an element ([8]), see: https://play.golang.org/p/yuhh4ZeJFNL

And also, you should interept the second byte as lowbyte of the int and the first as highbyte, not literally cut the binary string. for example `4` should be interept as `[0x0,0x4]` instead of `[0x4,0x0]` which shoulld be 1024.

If you want to keep using strconv you should use:

```
n := len(binary)
first := binary[:n-8]
last := binary[n-8:]
```

However it is very unefficient.

I would suggest `b[0],b[1] = i >> 8, i & 255`, and `i = b[0]<<8 + b[1]` .

Comment: can you please explain what is going on with all the bitwise ops and is there any resource where i can learn more about these ops i still have difficulties understanding why and how we use bitwise operations. All the resources explain what they do which i understand perfectly but none refers why we need those operations over binary.

In your example i understand the second part it moves the b[0] 8 bits left and adds b[1] which makes perfect sense but the first part im totally lost @leafBebop

Comment: You mean low and high *byte*, not 'bit'.

Comment: 255 is basically 11111111 which is a mask of the lower bytes. It is rather a simple bit-op. To understand why you need a bit-ops you may need to learn how the machine work, what is a byte and how are ints stored. However, I did not learn all these in English, so I cannot recommend resources.