# base64 string length calculation when encoding unsigned integers only

Tags: python, go, encoding, base64

I am trying to figure out estimates for how many unsigned integer numbers I can encode with 5 characters of base64, 6 characters, and so on.

Through programmatic approach I found out that I can encode

```
2^28 - 1 = 268,435,455
```

with 6 characters and

```
2^35 - 1 = 34,359,738,368
```

with 7 characters.

(-1 because I start at uint 1)

I am struggling to generalize this though, since I would assume it starts at `2^8 = 256` but I don't get how I end up at `28` and `35`.

This is my implementation in Go

```
func Shorten(num uint64) string {
    buf := make([]byte, binary.MaxVarintLen64)
    n := binary.PutUvarint(buf, num)
    b := buf[:n]
    encoded := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(b)
    return strings.Replace(encoded, "=", "", -1)
}
```

Also

```
0 -> AA
128 -> gAE
16384 -> gIAB
2097152 -> gICAAQ
268435456 -> gICAgAE
```

So it looks like it's going up in 7 increments: 2^7, 2^14, 2^21, etc. but why 7?

Comment: Base64 is not fixed length. It is variable and sometimes ends up with padding on the end.  Base64 has 64 characters that represent 6 bits each. Hence, 3 bytes will convert to 4 Base64 letters (hence, why you could have padding show up because they are not even). Why not write an exhaust to see what converts?

Comment: Have you looked at `Encoding.EncodedLen()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A byte is 8 bits and therefore 256 possible values. Base 64 uses 64 different characters to encode and therefore is using 6 bits. so how many 8 bit objects can you fit in 6 bits? 0 if you're rounding or 3/4 if you aren't. When you start talking about encoding integers however your numbers do not appear to make sense. Are you talking about integers written in ascii? with 6 base64 characters you have 36 bits to play with so if you're talking about binary 32-bit unsigned integers you can encode one at a time but you can encode any of them that you want for 2**32 different possibilities and then 4 wasted bits. With ascii you'd have 4 characters so it would be 10000 different possibilities (0 to 9999).

You are getting unexpected results because you're using go varints which are not encoded as regular binary integers. some ipython output for you:

```
In [22]: base64.b64encode((128).to_bytes(1,'little'))                                                                                          
Out[22]: b'gA=='
```

because 128 can be encoded in a single 8 bit byte it is only 2 characters with some padding. and look at this:

```
In [3]: base64.b64decode('gAE=')                                                                                                               
Out[3]: b'\x80\x01'

In [4]: int.from_bytes(_,'little')                                                                                                             
Out[4]: 384
```

So as you can see PutUVarint isn't just encoding an integer of variable length it's encoding a variable integer, ie it has been encoded in a way that it can be decoded without knowing in advance what size it is. If you look at the [source code for the varint go module](https://golang.org/src/encoding/binary/varint.go) it describes this process. Go is using 7 bits of each byte to hold actual integer binary data and the most significant bit is a flag as to whether or not there is more data yet to come. 128 is just the most significant bit of one byte set. So basically you're encoding twice based on the way you're accomplishing this task. If you have a given integer to encode it as a var int you need the number of bytes that the integer uses *8/7 to store the value then you base64 encode that result so you need that value *8/6 to store that. Depending on what you're doing with the base64 you can likely determine how many bytes you're playing with without needing to resort to the go varints and then the calculation would just be the 8/6 conversion (which is 4/3 I just left it in bits to match the varint process more closely.)

Comment: No integers written as ASCII but the integer converted to bytes and passed to the base64 encoding. I've attached an example above in Go how that would look like.

Comment: Please see my updated answer and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I assume there is a method in Go which is more efficient in decoding a larger space of number

Comment: you can find a discussion about the topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888357/convert-an-integer-to-a-byte-array

Of course you'll have to specify how many bytes you want to serialise the int to and you'll have to know on the other end in order to convert it back to an int.